# Bot framework async issues

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, botframework

I'm experimenting with the translation service on the Microsoft bot framework.  I've written a method to which I pass a callback function which receives my translated text.

I've got an existing bot that calls an HTTP endpoint to create my output in English.  I want to translate the output to the different language before returning it to the user.  My unaltered code looks like this:

```
await request.post(ENDPOINT,
    {
        headers: HEADERS,
        json: BODY
    },
    async function (error, response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode == 202) {
            var msg = body.mainResponse.text;
            context.sendActivity(msg);
        }
    });
```

This runs just fine.  Data passed in the HTTP response body gets parsed sent back to the user.

Now I want to plug in my translation service.  I've got a single function that I call to do this called `Translator.translate(text, callback)`.  I've added this call to my existing function to get:

```
await request.post(ENDPOINT,
    {
        headers: HEADERS,
        json: BODY
    },
    async function (error, response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode == 202) {
            var msg = body.mainResponse.text;
            await Translator.translate(msg, function (output) {
                context.sendActivity(output);
            });
        }
    }
);
```

My translation process runs and I get the translation in the `output` variable, but nothing gets sent back to the user.  Looking at the terminal, I see the error  "Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked" relating to the `context.sendActivity` line in my callback.

Can anyone suggest how I keep the context object active?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using BotBuilder V3 or V4? And by the translation service on the Microsoft bot framework do you mean the Translator Text API in Azure?

Comment: V4, I believe.  Yes to the Translator Text API.  My translator module is basically a variation of the code in this tutorial here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-nodejs-translate

Comment: Try awaiting `context.sendActivity`. Its containing function should be async of course.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Thank you - I tried this and I made some progress, but still got some weird issues - see comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for the assistance everyone - I never completely got to the bottom of this, but I finally fixed it with a complete re-write of the code.  I think the problem was caused by a large number of nested synchronous and asynchronous calls.  My ultimate solution was to completely get rid of all the nesting - first calling the translation service (and waiting for it), then doing the original call.

I think there are a number of other asynchronous threads inside the methods of both pieces of functionality.  I don't have a great understanding of how this works in node, but I'm guessing that the response was getting popped off the stack at the wrong point, which is why I wasn't seeing it.  The "cannot perform get" error was a bit of a red herring, it turns out.  I get the same error from some of Microsoft's working demo code.  I'm sure there's a separate issue there that ought to be fixed, but it wasn't actually caused by this issue.  The code was running, but the output was getting lost.

Comment: can you please look at this issue which i am facing. Can you please help with your solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628312/amazon-lex-and-botframework-integration-typeerror-cannot-perform-get-on-a-pro